# How is Hyperledger REST Server's Authentication Token (via Google OAuth) different to Google's OAauth Token

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have set up the composer rest server to authenticate for multi-user use via OAuth2.

I set this up to use google OAuth2 as this is what my app uses as well for user login

The issue is that the token that google returns via the app differs to what the hyperledger rest server api returns out despite using the same gmail.

This means that when I try supplying the token from the app to create a transaction on the rest server I am receiving an authentication error.

I have tried using https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?access_token= to see if the tokens are valid.

The token from the app is valid, the token from the rest server is not valid. This is where I am confused as the rest server is set up to use google's oauth so why is the token within hyperledger not valid?

I assume the rest sever is changing the token into some other format. My key question is what is that format?

I am following all the steps and using the code from here (with my clientid and secret, which I will not share here).

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest

I would like to be able to use the valid google token from google's oauth to authenticate hyperledger transactions via the rest server. This likely requires converting google's token format into hyperledger's token format.